# How can I use ExecuteScalar command for null returns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oledb

I have Oledbconnection like this(this is sample code):

```
public string var1, var2;
...
OleDbConnection Connection;
    Connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=" +
               Server.MapPath("~/db.mdb"));

OleDbCommand Command1, Command2;

Command1 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT DT FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1", Connection);
Command2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT GT FROM Table1 WHERE ID = 1", Connection);

Connection.Open();
var1= (string)Command1.ExecuteScalar();
var2= (string)Command2.ExecuteScalar();
Connection.Close();
```

When Oledbcommand getting null, ExecuteScalar getting error.

I can use try-catch or I can control if object is null or not. But is it possible easy way to do it? I just want if query getting null, I want to set null var1 and var2.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand. Just check `if(var1 == null)` or something?

Comment: Implement a null check,

Comment: if query null, i want to set like this: `var1 = "";`. Because if oledbcommand getting null, executescalar does not work.

Comment: for assigning you can use the null coalescing operator

var1= (string)   (Command1.ExecuteScalar() ?? "");
which means "" is returned if execute Scalar is returning null. Don`t forget to check for dbnull afterwards

Answer (score 3):

you have to check if the return value equals [DBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var result1 = Command1.ExecuteScalar(); //you get an object here, not a string
if (result1 != DBNull.Value && result1 != null)
{
   var1 = (string)result1;
}
```